# Executable JAR built with maven unable to find resources when loaded from static method

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

So I have a small resource loader for stuff that I need. The jar packages the resources but when I build the maven project, and all the dependencies work and resources folder is marked as resources, my images and scripts wont load.

Here is the code I am using:

```
...

public class ResourceLoader
{
    public static ImageIcon getImageIconResource(String fileName) {
        ClassLoader classLoader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
        File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("img/" + fileName).getFile());
        return new ImageIcon(file.getPath());
    }

    public static File getScriptResource(String fileName) {
        ClassLoader classLoader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
        return new File(classLoader.getResource("scripts/" + fileName).getFile());
    }
}
```

Comment: You should not load resources as files...keep them as resources..best is to handle it via `getResourcesAsStream(..)` cause you should keep in mind that later the resources are inside a jar file ...

Comment: @khmarbaise how do i put them in imageicons or files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not with maven itself. When you call

```
File.getPath
```

on File from the resource it points to a File, that is actually **inside** of your application archive. For most applications, this pose a problem because you cannot read file without extracting the archive. To correctly use resource file, you have to work with File, or you can call

```
ClassLoader.getResourcesAsStream
```

To adress ImageIcon

```
public static ImageIcon getImageIconResource(String fileName) {
    ClassLoader classLoader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
    InputStream is = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("img/" + fileName);
    Image image = ImageIO.read(is);
    return new ImageIcon(image);
}
```

As for your getScriptResource method geting File object should work. But that depends, on how you will later use it. As I think you will need to read it anyway at some point I suggest using input stream as well.

```
public static InpoutStream getScriptResource(String fileName) {
    ClassLoader classLoader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
    InputStream is = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("scripts/" + fileName);    
    return is;
}
```

Then, you can read the InputStream using many options that suits your need. For example, you can take a look at [Apache Commons' IoUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html) or handle it using [ReaderApi](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-io/readers-writers.html)

**EDIT:**

Because you have clarified how you will use your file I can see where is the problem with your scripts. You are starting another process outside of your application. In the first CLI param of python3, you are providing path to the file. As I wrote earlier - this is the problem, because python3 cannot read file inside of .jar file. First of all, I would have questioned your architecture. Do you really need to have script inside of .jar?

Anyway, one possible workaround may be storing contents of a script File in temporaryFile.

```
File tempFile = File.createTempFile("prefix-", "-suffix");
// e.g.: File tempFile = File.createTempFile("MyAppName-", ".tmp");
tempFile.deleteOnExit();
//get your script and prepare OutputStream to tempFile
// Try with resources, because you want to close your streams
try (InputStream is = ResourceLoader.getScriptResource(scriptName);
     FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(tempFile)) {
    //NOTE: You can use any method to copy InputStream to OutputStream.
    //Here I have used Apache IO Utils
    IOUtils.copy(is, out);
}
boolean success = executePythonScriptWithArgs(tempFile, args);
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer! Images work great but I need to be able to run my files in a process, using this code: https://pastebin.com/uZ0E7ULg - Any way that I can do this?

Comment: I have edited my answer  to better adress your problem.